# Questions about statements like "Since $\epsilon$ is arbitary".

Tags: analysis

When studying real analysis, I encounter the following argument:

> Fix $\epsilon$ > 0. 
> (after some deduction...) 
> We have $a-\epsilon < x < b+\epsilon$. 
> **Since $\epsilon$ is arbitary**, we have $a < x < b$.

May I ask if this argument correct? If yes, what is the intuition of the statement "**Since $\epsilon$ is arbitary**" in this argument? Isn't no matter how small the $\epsilon$ I choose, we will never have $a < x < b$?

Comment: It is incorrect. You can only say $a \leq x \leq b$.

Comment: The intuition is to "take the limit" as $\epsilon$ goes to $0$.

Comment: Consider the case $a=x=b$ , then for every $\epsilon>0$ , we still have $a-\epsilon<x<b+\epsilon$ , hence , as mentioned , the conclusion is invalid.

Comment: Let's simplify. Say you want to show, if $x < b + \varepsilon$ for any positive $\varepsilon$, then $x \le b$ (as others have pointed out, strict inequality cannot be concluded). You can prove this by contradiction. Assume $x > b$. If this is the case, then $\varepsilon = x - b$ is one such positive number. But, this would mean that $x < b + (x - b)$, i.e. $x < x$. This is a contradiction. You can do something similar with $a - \varepsilon < x$.